# access Websocket traffic from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

There is a page (game), which communicate via WebSocket to the server. I can see the data (frames) in the Chrome Developer Tool. Is it possible to access / modify this communication from a chrom-extension?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently, the only way to access or modify Websocket traffic is to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to [inject a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) that replaces the `WebSocket` constructor with your own wrapper. This wrapper should behave like the original WebSocket implementation, but you can add more stuff, like logging the sent/received messages to your extension.

To prevent sites from breaking, you must make sure that your `WebSocket` wrapper is fully standard-compliant. The interface that has to be implemented is documented at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/network.html#the-websocket-interface.

For inspiration on how to wrap a DOM constructor, see e.g. my [wrapper for `Worker`](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/blob/master/patch-worker/patch-worker.js). You are free to re-use parts of the code (e.g. the implementation of the `EventTarget` interface, which is also a requirement of the `WebSocket` API).

**More emphasis: Make sure that your implementation adheres to the interface of the standard WebSocket API, or you could break some sites!**

Comment: How would that work, considering that content scripts have sandboxed execution environment? It would not replace `WebSockets` used by the page.

Comment: @Xan Follow the "inject a script" link in my answer.

Comment: "My god, it's full of stars!" - thanks for sharing that

Comment: thank you! I have maneged to inject my script into the DOM. They use dojo-cometd for webSocket communication. My idea to overwrite the org.cometd.WebSocketTransport's onMessage function. The problem: my script.js fires before org.cometd's js loaded-> org is undefined. (although if i use console.log(org) i can see it).

Comment: here is the cometd.js http://pastebin.com/hecAcnus the WebSocketTransport function is in line 565.

Comment: @user1930254 I suggest to replace the WebSocket constructor instead of `WebSocketTransport`, so that you do not depend on the specific of the dojo-cometd library.

Comment: i think it should be now possible without your recommandation. Please see here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest, they say: "Starting from Chrome 58, the webRequest API supports intercepting the WebSocket handshake request. Since the handshake is done by means of an HTTP upgrade request, its flow fits into HTTP-oriented webRequest model. Note that the API does not intercept:"

Doesn't that mean that we now have acces websocket's traffic via chrome.webrequest api?

Comment: @CenkTen go read it again, it does not intercept websocket messages, only the upgrade

Answer (score 9):

Seems like the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129353) is fixed and available. In the manifest.json you need to explicitly specify the permissions

```json
{
  ...
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "ws://*/*", "wss://*/*"]
  ...
}
```

and in the network filters it should be specified as a websocket request.

```js
const networkFilters = {
    urls: [
        "wss://echo.websocket.org/*"
    ]
};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
    const { tabId, requestId } = details;
    // do stuff here
}, networkFilters);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a WebSocket-Wrapper, you can use it to access WebSocket traffic:

https://github.com/gorhill/chromium-websocket-wrapper/blob/master/chromium-websocket-wrapper.js

Answer (score 2):

Judging from discussion on [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129353), there is currently no API to intercept WebSocket traffic, unlike normal requests with `chrome.webRequest`. It's assigned but not completed yet.

Edit: recent (as of Nov 2016) activity on the bug suggests a patch in the works.

Comment: And still no API (6 Years Man), probably they don't want to add it to chrome because the extensions will misuse it too much

Answer (score -1):

I came across this question and tried solutions above, unfortunately the scripts in my target site still found WebSocket has been tampered and broke, which is bad.

So I come up with my own solution:

```
var ws = window.WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(a,b){
var ret = new ws(a,b);
let handle = setInterval(function(){
                  if(ret.onmessage){
                     clearInterval(handle);
                     let o = ret.onmessage;
                     ret.onmessage = function(m){
                                       //do what your want to m
                                       o(m);
                                     };
                   }
                   },50);
                   return ret;
              }
```

If the site you want to inspect does use WebSocket, I will definitely assign to `onmessage` sometime after creating WebSocket object, just check it periodically and reassign it with your own function.